# JavaFX removing performed action if checkbox is unselected

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox

I am a beginner messing around with JavaFX. In my program, when a checkbox is selected I want it to display a label along with a ChoiceBox. However, when it is unselected, I want both of these to disappear. I'm not quite sure how to do this however.

Here is my code:

```
String [] options = new String [] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
CheckBox [] cbs = new CheckBox[options.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        final CheckBox cb = cbs[i] = new CheckBox(options[i]);
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if(observable.getValue() == true){
                    ChoiceBox<Integer> choice = new ChoiceBox<>();
                    Label label = new Label("How many of the selected accounts do you have?");
                    choice.getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                    choice.setValue(1);
                    selection.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
                    selection.getChildren().addAll(label, choice);
                    gp.add(selection, 0, 8);
                } else if (observable.getValue() == false){
                    // remove above block if getValue() == false;
                }
            }
       });
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the nodes. You could do this by adding fields to the anonymus `ChangeListener` or by adding a (effectively) final local variable to the loop body.

I'm not sure what `selection` is, but using the same node for multiple checkboxes seems like a bad idea.

The following example simply adds/removes a `VBox` containing the `Label` and `ChoiceBox`. Since this changes the layout though, I recommend disabling the nodes instead or changing the visibility instead of adding/removing the nodes.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    String[] options = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        final int row = i;
        String option = options[i];
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(option);

        ChoiceBox<Integer> choice = new ChoiceBox<>();
        Label label = new Label("How many of the selected accounts do you have?");
        choice.getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        VBox choiceContainer = new VBox(label, choice);

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                grid.add(choiceContainer, 1, row);
            } else {
                grid.getChildren().remove(choiceContainer);
            }
        });

        grid.add(checkBox, 0, row);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```